# Cascading DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC using TELERIK

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I started learning ASP.NET and telerik 3 days ago, and I need some help concerning cascading drop down lists, I really cannot detect the source of the problem, I need help.

Below are the codes

Here is the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("months")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
              .OptionLabel("Select month...")
              .DataTextField("MonthName")
              .DataValueField("MonthID")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeMonths", "Home")
                          .Data("filterMonths");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("years")
)
<script>
            function filterMonths() {
                return {
                    years: $("#years").val()
                };
            }
</script>
```

and here is the controller:

```
   public ActionResult GetCascadeMonths(int YearCode)
        {
            IQueryable months = Month.GetMonths().Where(x => x.YearCode == YearCode);

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(
                                months,
                                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );

            return View(months);
        }
```

and here is the model:

```
public class Month
{
    public int YearCode { get; set; }
    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    public String MonthName { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<Month> GetMonths()
    {
        return new List<Month>
        {
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=1,
                    MonthName = "January"
                },
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=2,
                    MonthName = "February"
                },
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=3,
                    MonthName = "March"
                },
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=4,
                    MonthName = "April"
                },
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=5,
                    MonthName = "May"
                },
            new Month
                {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    MonthID=6,
                    MonthName = "June"
                }
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to tell what the problem is

Comment: Your sending `{ years: $("#years").val() }` but your method expect a property named `YearCode` (not `years`)

Comment: I am sorry, the problem is for example when we choose 2016 as a year ( YearCode = 1), the dropdown list of the months contains no options

Comment: Right,but sorry I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @Skhwab, how about renaming one of these to match the other?

Comment: Just for testing use `.Data({ YearCode: 1 });` (currently I don't think you even calling your `filterMonths()` function)

Comment: @Andrei, I tried and it didn't work

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, It worked with .Data({ YearCode: 1 });

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `Kendo`  `DataSource` syntax so I'm not sure if `.Data("filterMonths");` actually calls your function, but if it does, then the function needs to be `return { yearCode: $("#years").val() };`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, It worked, You saved my life, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andrei, Thank you for your help.